# Recamans sequence for 20132014th term

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, sequence

I want a algorithm to generate recamans term within 30 second as given in the problem!

Java code:

```
int a0=0;
int a1;
System.out.println("Enter the term for which Recman sequence need to be calculated");
int n=Integer.parseInt(bfr.readLine());

list.add(a0);
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    a1 = a0 - i;
    if(a1 > 0 && !list.contains(a1))
    {
        a0 = a1;
        list.add(a0);
    }
    else
    {
        a1 = a0 + i;
        a0 = a1;
        list.add(a0);
    }
    System.out.println(a0);
}
System.out.println("The" + n + "th term is " + a0);
}
}
```

The program runs indefinitely, is there any alternate algorithm to generate the result in 30 second?

Comment: We can't see the image that you tried to link. Can you update your question to include this image?

Comment: The question is from my college assignment that to find **20132014th** term of recamans sequence below 30 second,the question also states that there is a algorithm that will generate in 30  second ,i tried myself using basic iteration,also googled for fast algorithm,so i didnt find one.hence if u people can give me hint ,**any algorithm that tremendously fast enough to generate the term** OR is the question just testing my reasoning that such algorithm is not possible.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the definition of the Recamans sequence? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: this is the sequence http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecamansSequence.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your list to `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` 
This should speed things up. The `HashMap` 
will map the index `N` to the sequence element `a[N]`.
Also, see if you get an overflow i.e. if `Integer` type
is large enough for generating the terms you want.

From what I see here, it seems this sequence does not
grow quickly at all. So I doubt you'll get an overflow
for reasonable-sized N.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecamansSequence.html

http://oeis.org/A005132

http://oeis.org/A005132/b005132.txt

Answer (score 0):

Sure: don't use a list; instead, use a set data structure, that supports quick lookups. The culprit of your current implementation is probably the `list.contains(a1))` part.